# How to add special characters through the number raw?

Tags: javascript

### I have generated random number. So i want to add some specific places to special characters

**As a example** - nuzmo2b2yhougkpntd5srif0fdami12_f6gyve0acaddzmt_rbz0iwlizmioiwdmlj

This is the how to genarate random numbers.

```
    let randomkey = [...Array(64)].map(() => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('')
    console.log(randomkey)
```

As well as i tried to use **splice** but it doesn't work

```
let updatedkey = randomkey.splice(20 , 0 , "_")
```

This says **splice** is not a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.splice` is not a method of string ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)), so to use that, you should convert it to array of character using `.split('')`, then do `.splice`, then convert back to string using `.join('')`

```js
let randomkey = [...Array(64)].map(() => Math.random().toString(36)[2]).join('')
console.log(randomkey)

let updatedkey = randomkey.split('')
updatedkey.splice(20, 0, "_")
updatedkey = updatedkey.join('')

console.log(updatedkey)
```

Comment: In case `randomkey` doesn't need to be used before insert the special characters, it would be better not to use `.join('')` and `.split('')` but just use `.join('')` after insert the desired characters into `randomkey` array to convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript String `slice()` method:

```
let updatedkey = randomkey.slice(0, 20) + "_" + randomkey.slice(20);
```